# How to get the value of OnClientClick Return with yes or no buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I know how to get the return confirm box to popup on the button click but in my case, I only want to get which button was clicked by the user ("yes" or "no). Once the client clicks on the AddToCartBtn I am redirecting them to another url. I want them to be redirected to the URL no matter what they click on but with the Return Confirm, it will cancel the redirect at the moment when the click no. Should I be using something other than "Confirm" in this case to receive the value that the user chose and continue to redirect them to a new page afterwards? The only code I have so far is only for the simple confirmation popup.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AddToCartBtn" runat="server" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'
ImageUrl="~/Pictures/ShoppingCart.png"                                          
OnClick="AddToCartBtn_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('are you sure?')" />
```

I have been unable to find much else although I found a custom popup in javascript that includes a checkbox which the checkbox control could take place of the yes or no buttons just as long as I can get the value but I am not able to get this to work, I will include this code also just in case this is the direction I should be going in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('AddToCartBtn').click(function() {
var answer = $("#dialog").dialog()
    .find(':checkbox').unbind('change').bind('change', function(e){
    if(this.checked) alert('checked box');
    else alert('unchecked box');
});
})
</script>

<button>CLICK ME</button>

<div id='illegal'></div>

<div id='numberplateyellow'></div>

<div id='numberplatewhite'></div>

<div id='dialog'>
The registration you have entered is illegal for the uk roads. By clicking ok you are accepting          full resposibility for this plate and agreeing to use it for offroad use only.
<br/>
  Check here if you agree to the terms and conditions: <input type='checkbox'/>
</div>
```

I am not use to using javascript with asp.net so I am not exactly sure how I call this javascript in the onClick event for my button. The button and  containers below the javascript code are test examples from a site but in my case I need the button to be my asp:ImageButton "AddToCartBtn" instead of the html button. So to recap, Is there a way to use the return confirm popup and get the value that the user clicked on, but still redirect them to the page if they click no? Or should I be going more towards the custom checkbox popup, and if so how can I get the example I listed for the checkbox to work with my asp:imageButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your `OnClientClick` with the call to a function:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AddToCartBtn" runat="server" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' ImageUrl="~/Pictures/ShoppingCart.png" OnClick="AddToCartBtn_Click" OnClientClick="return Redirect();" />
```

The JS function:

```
function Redirect() {
    var result = confirm('Are you sure?');

    // Do something with result.

    return true; // return true no matter what the user clicked.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to call it by `OnClientClick="Redirect()"` and It wasn't doing anything for me.

Comment: From the code above `$('AddToCartBtn').click(function()` How would I call this function? What is the name of it or is this more like an event?

Comment: Well, in that code you are attaching the "function" to click event of the object "AddToCartBtn". If you want to call it somewhere just take it out, give it a name and call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ModalPopupExtender rather than a js confirm.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="AddToCartBtn" runat="server" RowIndex='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>'
ImageUrl="~/Pictures/ShoppingCart.png" />

<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSure" Text="Are you sure?" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" Text="YES" OnClick="AddToCartBtn_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="NO" />
</asp:Panel>

<ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe" runat="server"     
    TargetControlID="AddToCartBtn" 
    PopupControlID="pnlPopup" 
    OkControlID="btnYes"
    CancelControlID="btnNo" />
```